# How I can send Multiple TVPs in Nodejs with MSSQL?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, async-await, table-valued-parameters

I'm trying to send Multiple Tvps to the procedure using npm i mssql

```
exports.createNewApplication = async (req, res) => {
try {
 const ServidorConfig = serverConfig();

 const applicationTable = new sql.Table();

 applicationTable.columns.add("id_aplicacion", sql.Int());
 applicationTable.columns.add("producto_aplicado", sql.NVarChar());
 applicationTable.columns.add("fecha_aplicacion", sql.Date());
 applicationTable.columns.add("dosis", sql.Decimal());
 applicationTable.columns.add("eliminado", sql.Bit());

 applicationTable.rows.add(5, "testNode", new Date("2022-03-21"), 13.2, 0);


 const applicationPortionsTable = new sql.Table();

 applicationPortionsTable.columns.add("id_aplicacion",sql.Int)
 applicationPortionsTable.columns.add("id_lote",sql.Int)

 applicationPortionsTable.rows.add(5,1)

 const fuidVarBinary = Buffer.from("42C7F1C99233D000", "utf16le");

 const pool = await sql.connect(ServidorConfig);
 const result = await pool.request()
                .input("type", sql.TinyInt, 2)
                .input("applications", sql.TVP, applicationTable)
                .input("applications_portions", sql.TVP, applicationPortionsTable)
                .input("id_company", sql.Int,1 )
                .input("FUID", sql.VarBinary, fuidVarBinary)
                .execute("brb_CRUD_applications")

 console.log(result)

} catch (error) {

 console.log(error)
 }
};
```

But I get an error

> RequestError: The number NaN cannot be converted to BigInt because it is not an integer
> at Request.userCallback (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:808:19)
> at Request.callback (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:205:14)
> at Parser.onEndOfMessage (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2854:22)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:519:28)
> at Parser.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at Readable. (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:32:12)
> at Readable.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
> code: 'EREQUEST',
> originalError: RangeError: The number NaN cannot be converted to BigInt because it is not an integer
> at Function.BigInt (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\jsbi\dist\jsbi-cjs.js:1:366)
> at WritableTrackingBuffer.writeUInt64LE (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\tracking-buffer\writable-tracking-buffer.js:161:41)
> at Object.generateParameterData (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\data-types\decimal.js:101:14)
> at generateParameterData.next ()
> at Object.generateParameterData (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\data-types\tvp.js:96:28)
> at generateParameterData.next ()
> at RpcRequestPayload.generateParameterData (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\rpcrequest-payload.js:120:17)
> at generateParameterData.next ()
> at RpcRequestPayload.generateData (D:\Test\FitoMasivo\testLibrary\node_modules\tedious\lib\rpcrequest-payload.js:70:19)
> at generateData.next (),
> number: undefined,
> lineNumber: undefined,
> state: undefined,
> class: undefined,
> serverName: undefined,
> procName: undefined,
> precedingErrors: []
> }

So my question is: How to send multiples TVPs to let me performance the query

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/parameters.html), "TVP are only supported when using callProcedure."

Comment: I tried to use tedious with the callProcedure but got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the non-declaration of the precision and scale of the Type Decimal but the error displayed was not correct

```
applicationTable.columns.add("dosis", sql.Decimal(10,3));
```